# Use I/O redirection between two scripts without waiting for the first to finish

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipeline, io-redirection

I have two scripts, let's say long.sh and simple.sh: one is very time consuming, the other is very simple. The output of the first script should be used as input of the second one.

As an example, the "long.sh" could be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for line in `cat LONGIFLE.dat` do;
    # read line;
    # do some complicated processing (time consuming);
    echo $line
done;
```

And the simple one is:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read a; do
    # simple processing;
    echo $a + "other stuff"
done;
```

I want to pipeline the two scripts this:

```
sh long.sh | sh simple.sh
```

Using pipelines, the simple.sh has to wait the end of the long script before it could start.

I would like to know if in the bash shell it is possible to see the output of simple.sh per current line, so that I can see at runtime what line is being processed at this moment.

I would prefer not to merge the two scripts together, nor to call the simple.sh inside long.sh.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that the whole point of a pipeline is that the right-hand side does *not* have to wait for the left-hand side to complete, as is the case if you use a temporary file such as `sh long.sh > tmp; sh simple.sh < tmp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stdout is normally buffered. You want line-buffered. Try

```
stdbuf -oL sh long.sh | sh simple.sh
```

Note that this loop

```
for line in `cat LONGIFLE.dat`; do   # see where I put the semi-colon?
```

reads **words** from the file. If you only have one word per line, you're OK. Otherwise, to read by lines, use `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done < LONGFILE.dat`

Always quote your variables (`echo "$line"`) unless you know specifically when not to.

Comment: This is a good instinct, but experimentation shows that the echo inside the loop of long.sh is not buffered.  (I'm curious if there is a standard that clarifies if echo has a builtin must not buffer, but clearly /bin/echo cannot add its output to the shell's buffering.)  Try `sh long.sh | stdbuf -oL sh simple.sh` istead.